# Updating a converted document using the Google Drive API

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I am using the Google Drive API (C#) to both create and update documents. They are edited locally as open document (.odt). When I create a document, using conversion, everything works fine. When I try and update an existing document, something goes wrong and what ends up at the server is gibberish. In fact, in looks a lot like a text rendering of the raw odt file. Has anyone experienced this and can they help?

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure you are passing `convert=true` to the update method.

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update